# Python macro in regular expression

Tags: python, macros, python-2.7

In the below case i have used `"|"` condition in matching multiple search patterns and replacing all the search patterns with the value. It worked fine. But Does python has any MACRO type of thing where i can write all the patterns in it and call that in the search pattern? and replace all the patterns at once. Because i have to write almost 20 to 30 search patterns. Please help me in implementing this.

Thanks in Advance.

```
import re

st = '''<h5>Reglar</h5>
<h5>Lateral</h5>
<h5>Daily</h5>
<h5>Weekly</h5>
<h5>Monthly</h5>
<h5>Quaterly</h5>
<h5>Yearly</h5>
<h5>Halfyearly</h5>'''

vr = re.sub(r'(?i)<h5>(Lateral|Halfyearly|Monthly)</h5>', "<h5>FINAL</h5>", st)
print vr
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you want to replace a list of search terms?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to pre-compile your patterns? (re.compile)?

Comment: In general, you [don't want to use regular expressions to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6751339/1142167). Look into an actual HTML parser such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: @Mike yes i am planning to replace a list of search items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does not have macros.

I am not certain to understand for sure what you are after but:

Strings containing the regular expression can be build programmatically:

```
frequncy_str = ('Lateral', 'Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly')
re_str = '(?i)<h5>(' + '|'.join(frequency_str) + ')</h5>'
```

For better performances, if the match is going to be performed several times one should compile the regular expression:

```
  re_pat = re.compile(re_str)
```

Comment: Firstly Thanks for the reply.Think I am planning to replace a set of search patterns with same value (In the above example i have replaced all the search patterns with "FINAL" value). I tried using the above code but i am not getting through.